# Is there a way to see all the transactions coming through my Monero node?

Tags: full-node, transaction-data, nodes, monerujo

I'm running `monerod` on my Ubuntu server and if I create a transaction using Monerujo using my node to process it, can I see it in my `monerod` console? If not, how can I see the transactions going through my node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You will need to increase the log level in the daemon. E.g. `set_log +daemon.rpc:DEBUG` should suffice.

Comment: so the command to run would be: **./monerod set_log +daemon.rpc:DEBUG** ?

Comment: If you're already in the daemon console just `set_log +daemon.rpc:DEBUG` or if not then yes, as you described (though may need to quote "+daemon.rpc:DEBUG")

Comment: where is this log file saved?

Comment: Either in the same directory as the executable, the current working directory of the process, or a location set via the `--log-file` parameter, or the ~/.bitmonero directory.